# how to store data specific to a user for one minute in laravel?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, laravel, push-notification, ionic-framework

i am building an app in ionic framework for my client, it uses laravel 5.2 as backend. i had a situation where a user sends a certain request e.g. job request with some data to the other user. the other user sees the request and data. he can accept or reject it. but the other user has only one minute to accept or reject it. a timer starts at the sender end if the reciever did not responded it within one minute. timer ends at reciever end and a popup is show "did not responded".

i have no idea how to do it. where to store the data for one minute. and after one minute data should be delete.

please help me i am stuck here for last one week.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a setTimeout function:

```
// Measured in nanoseconds
var ONE_MINUTE = 60000;
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
  // this code will run in exactly one minute. Reset the variable to ""
}, ONE_MINUTE);
```

On the inside of the setTimeout function you could use localStorage. That way if they closed their browser, they could still open it back up and have the value persisted. I normally would not recommend localStorage, but if you are storing it only for one minute, there's no harm. It would take some working with it, but you could call a function when the page initially loads so that the variable is loaded from localStorage (in case they closed their browser before the one minute timer expired) and start a new timer. To save a value in localStorage:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.setItem("variable_name", "value");
}
```

and

`var tempValue = localStorage.getItem("variable_name");` in order to retreive it.

Comment: i have done this on client end. i have set a timeout in my controller function. but the question is how to send it to the other user. he will get a notification when he opens the app he will see the request data. how to store this  data in server for one minute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to store the data with specific time, go through the below links

http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/

Comment: how the other user will access it?. i mean i  sent this data to other user. if he is not available and if he logged in after 30 seconds he should be able to see the requested data.